# How to get the information of all files in a directory and its sub-directories on an ASP.NET Razor page?

Tags: razor

I have a ASP.NET Razor (C#) page. On this page I need to display the information of files under a directory. Information includes file name, size, path, and time last modified.

How can I obtain such information?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the VB Code and ASP but it should give you the basis you need.

Place this in your Code Segment

```
Dim logFilesDirectoryInfo As New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath) & "\Import\LogFiles")
Dim Files() As System.IO.FileInfo = logFilesDirectoryInfo.GetFiles()
'FileListDataGrid is an ASP Object, and this binds the Files list to it
FileListDataGrid.DataSource = Files
FileListDataGrid.DataBind()
```

Here is your ASP Objects.  You can autogenerate columns, or create and populate them yourself as I have done for the columns I wanted, File Name, LastWriteTime and Length (which is file size).

```
        <asp:DataGrid runat="server" id="FileListDataGrid"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Navy" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="8pt" AllowSorting="true">
       <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkColumn Target="_blank" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="../Photos/{0}" DataNavigateUrlField="Name" DataTextField="Name" 
               HeaderText="File Name" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="LastWriteTime" HeaderText="Upload Date" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataFormatString="{0:d}" Visible="true" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Length" HeaderText="File Size"
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" 
            DataFormatString="{0:#,### bytes}" ItemStyle-Width="115px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      </Columns>
    </asp:DataGrid>
```